# Columns and Inline Center Image

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a 2 text column with a div in the center like below.

[image]

I am using this code:

```css
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
```

When I place another div within the div class, it formats to go into two columns. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle or some code so we can see you put forth an effort?

Comment: I know I could use something like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/aX47K/

Comment: But I would really like to stick with the -moz-column-count:3; -webkit-column-count:3; column-count:3; and I can't seem to figure out how to do that.. my reasoning for this is because I like how the column-count formats the text very nice and keeps the columns the same height.

Comment: For that fiddle and your image you provide, in the fiddle they have text-align left which does not care about the right edges. If you use `text-align: justify;` you will get the crisp paragraphs like in the image.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely prefer to use the column-count.. since I would prefer not to have to separate my text into two separate divs! Thanks so much I appreciate it

Comment: I would just use what is in the fiddle you provided, http://jsfiddle.net/aX47K/93/. I added the justified text-align and that seems how you want it.

Comment: I just found this great article on css-tricks! http://css-tricks.com/float-center/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these following CSS:

```
 <style type="text/css">
  .container{ background:#00FF00;width: 844px;text-align:center; margin: 0px auto;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;height: 450px;}
  .columns {background:#FF0000; width: 400px;border: 1px solid #595959; height: 450px;text-align:left;float:left; padding: 10px;left:5%;}
  .popup_middle_content{background:#FFFFFF; border: solid 1px black; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;background-color: white;z-index: 1; height: 50px; margin-top: -150px; width: 200px;margin-left: -100px; }
</style>
```

And check with these below divs:

```
  <div class="container">
       <div  class="columns">Left Paragraph contents...</div>
       <div  class="columns">Right Paragraph contents...</div>
       <div  class="popup_middle_content">CENTER DIV content...</div>
  </div>
```

It is works for me. I hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this to your request of keeping css columns.

Picked up the idea from here: http://css-tricks.com/float-center/ as per @Josh's suggestion.

See this updated fiddle of yours: **http://jsfiddle.net/aX47K/99/**

The trick is to use css `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements on each column (represented by divs), with fixed width and height and floated opposite. This will create a dummy space which we can then fill with our image (or another div) using absolute positioning.

```
/* the overall wrapping div acting as newspaper */
div.paper { position:relative; }

/* the div holding the columns */
div.wrap {
    column-count:2;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* the dummy space created from individual divs holding the content */
#col-1:before, #col-2:before { 
  content: ""; 
  width: 140px; 
  height: 160px; 
}
#col-1:before { 
  float: right; 
}
#col-2:before { 
  float: left; 
}

/* the image will then be placed in the dummy space created above */
img {
    width: 240px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 10%; left: 33%;
}
```

However, please note that this approach is still a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate class for

Just check below example

```
<div class="newspaper">enter code here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod     tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis     nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lo`enter code here`bortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea     commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in 
</div>
<div class="newspaper"> 
Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis     qui facit eorum     claritatem. 
Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
<div class="">
Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem.  
 Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are long done with this but I have an example here which might prove to be useful.  There is a bit of nuance here which I don't want to explain unless someone asks.  I think with a touch of jQuery we could nail it down.

Here is my Fiddle Example.  It is responsive as well so you can expand the window to see that.  Again it is kinda quickly done.  If you choose a responsive container just look for the subtle breakpoints.

```
img {
width:auto;
height:5em;
}

#right img {
    padding:1.5em 1.5em 1em 0;   
}

#left img {
    padding:1.5em 0 1em 1.5em ; 
}

#right {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-5.5em;
}

#left {
   float:right; 
margin-right:-5.5em;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/524Uj/2/)

Answer (score -2):

Try creating separate Div classes for everything and position your div  class for the div the place you wanted. Don't create Div tags , just create classes !