# Paragraph alignment in two divs with an image between them

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment, paragraph

how can i align my paragraph as shown in the following image

[image: this image].

I need to show a newspaper kind of thing in which this should be included.

The following is the html code i'm using

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="myImage"><img src="question.png"/></div>
```

and the css code is this

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}  

.right,.left{
height:300px;
width:200px;
float:left;
background:red;
margin:5px;
}

.myImage img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}

.myImage{
clear:both;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:150px;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Quick answer is 'Yes'.

Comment: Is it ok if you divide the left section into three divs and right section into three different divs.. That way it becomes easy, but I'm not sure that is what you are looking for!

Comment: Someone made a hack to do something like that here: http://css-tricks.com/float-center/. It basically involves floating empty elements. You have to know your image's width. Give it a look and reverse-engineer it.

Comment: @CubicleDragon, @skshoyeb in CSStricks, the image is wraping to the top, but how about Middle? http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/Zf5qc/ this is what I have tried so far. I am not sure how to wrap the text top of the inner div. I already gave `position:relative` and `top`. anyone has an idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774980/columns-and-inline-center-image/20786062#20786062

Answer (score 1):

Create the image element on the left side, floating to the right of the text. Misplace it to the right, half the image's width with "margin". Then, on the right div, create the same effect using a blank div, but inverted. Float the div to the left side of the text and misplace it to the left by half the width. Like this:

```
<style>
    .right, .left
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        float:left;
    }

    #real-img
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: -50px; /* half the width */
        margin-top: 125px; /* vertical align considering page height minus img half height */
    }

    #fake-img
    {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
        margin-left: -50px;
        margin-top: 125px;
    }
</style>
```

And the html:

```
<div class="left">
    <img src="imgurl" id="real-img" />
    [CONTENT_TEXT]
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div id="fake-img"></div>
    [CONTENT_TEXT]
</div>
```

All of this, of course, considering you hard-code all the sizes.