# centering image in the middle of 2 column paragraph

Tags: html, css

please help, I want to make html print able page but have a problem with the design.

the problem is I want to make image of QR Code in the center of 2 column paragraph link this
[image: design image]

I tried to use `display: flex` but the text get separate,
[image: my design]

how to make the image in the center but the div still 2 column and readable?
here is my full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <style>
            .description{
                display:flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .in{
                text-align: justify;
            }
            
            .en{
                text-align: justify;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="description">
            <div class="in"><p>The statues of Khotbuto and Angkotbuto are two giant statues flanking the entrance to the main gate of the East Java Pavilion which is a picture of the twin patihs of the Blambangan kingdom (the title for the king's trusted soldiers or king's guards and is also a palace soldier who is in charge of securing the kingdom under the government of "Prabu Menak Jinggo")</p></div>
            <img src="qr.png" width="150px" height="150px" class="cut-in"/>
            <div class="en"><p>The statues of Khotbuto and Angkotbuto are two giant statues flanking the entrance to the main gate of the East Java Pavilion which is a picture of the twin patihs of the Blambangan kingdom (the title for the king's trusted soldiers or king's guards and is also a palace soldier who is in charge of securing the kingdom under the government of "Prabu Menak Jinggo")</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990517/paragraph-alignment-in-two-divs-with-an-image-between-them  Same kind of question. check it out

Comment: thank you @SureshPonnukalai the reference really help me, :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paragraph alignment in two divs with an image between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990517/paragraph-alignment-in-two-divs-with-an-image-between-them)

Comment: the answer of the question is helping me but still cant make the block to the center of paragraph